# Express over Node.js routing - Cannot Get /

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get

I'm building my first node/express app and am following a tut, erroring at step 2 at [this link](https://blog.lucius.digital/headless-drupal-node-js-part-3-3-express-js-and-drupal-api-integration-97f62de2d255).

I've was able to route data to the template through the app.get render function. In the next step I attempted to move the routes to index.js in the routes directory, and this is where I am getting an error.

**Directory Structure**

[image: directory structure for app]

**hellotest.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var routes = express.Router('./routes/index');

app.set('view engine','ejs');

var server = app.listen (2000, function(){ console.log('Waiting for you on port 2000'); });

app.use('/', routes);
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var routes = express.Router('./routes/index');

app.get ('/', function(req, res){ res.render('default',{title: 'Home', body: 'Datatest'}); });

app.get ('/about-us', function(req, res){ res.send('<h1>Lucius Websystems</h1>Amsterdam, The Netherlands'); });

app.get ('/about/:name?', function(req, res){ var name = req.params.name; res.send('<h1>' +name +'</h1>About text'); });
```

**Browser Error**

[image: error cannot get /]

There are no CLI errors.

I have carefully gone through the tutorial several times and I think there is a step missing (or implied) when decoupling the routing.

Can someone please help me understand why I am getting the Cannot Get / error and how I can properly route the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close! The issue is that you're defining your `app` in two different places.

Instead, your `index.js` should export the router to the server you instantiate in `hellotest.js`.

Index.js should look like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = express.Router();

routes.get('/', function(req, res){ res.render('default',{title: 'Home', body: 'Datatest'}); });

routes.get('/about-us', function(req, res){ res.send('<h1>Lucius Websystems</h1>Amsterdam, The Netherlands'); });

routes.get('/about/:name?', function(req, res){ var name = req.params.name; res.send('<h1>' +name +'</h1>About text'); });

module.exports = routes;
```

And `hellotest.js` should have this line at the top:

`var routes = require('./routes/index');`